# Java Document Literal WebService - MonoTouch client getting exception during WS response

Tags: soap, xamarin.ios, jax-ws, webservice-client

I am running a Java Document Literal WebService using JAX-WS over tomcat with the network being on HTTPS.  The Java & .Net WS clients are working fine while MonoTouch client over iOS is throwing Exception during response from WebService.  I have checked that the request gets hit on the server properly but the response that returns to MonoTouch client throws the following Exception on random WebService responses (some responses are successful):

```
[System.Xml.XmlException: Document element did not appear.  Line 1, position 1.
  at Mono.Xml2.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00168] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextReader.cs:629 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x0006b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlTextReader2.cs:564 
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent () [0x00050] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml/XmlReader.cs:563 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHelper.ReadSoapMessage (System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer bodySerializer, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer headerSerializer, Boolean soap12, System.Object& body, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderCollection& headers) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/WebServiceHelper.cs:187 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHelper.ReadSoapMessage (System.Xml.XmlTextReader xmlReader, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMethodStubInfo method, SoapHeaderDirection dir, Boolean soap12, System.Object& body, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderCollection& headers) [0x00011] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/WebServiceHelper.cs:182 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReceiveResponse (System.Net.WebResponse response, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage message, System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExtension[] extensions) [0x00149] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:322 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (System.String method_name, System.Object[] parameters) [0x000b8] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:379
```

On iOS client side, we are monitoring the net traffic and getting connection resets by peer with all the responses even though some responses are returning fine.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not receiving a valid XML response. It could be the service did not like your request and returned an (HTML) error message (e.g. 500).

An easy way to see what's going on is to use WireShark (or a similar tool to sniff network traffic) and run the application from the iOS simulator. The captured data should show your request and the response from the server. That will tell you for sure if it's an XML response or, if it's not, the error message you're getting back.

Comment: Fiddler would actually be the preferred tool here if the connection runs over https.  Also look for empty responses (zero-length content) - I'm not sure whether WebServiceHelper would catch and report them in a reasonably way, but the error message from XmlReader would look about the same.